# If a line is matched the regex => key, all lines after that => its value until the next match

Tags: ruby, hash

I have data look like

```
>header\n
something1\n
something2\n
something3\n
>header2\n ...
```

I want everything that start with > to be a key, all the rest is its value until the next header. What should I do to create hash by Ruby in this format?

```
{{:>header=>"something1something2something3"},
 {:>header2=>"something4something5something6"}, ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Regex

This regex scans for a line beginning with `>`, followed by other lines with characters that aren't `>`:

```
str = ">header
something1
something2
something3
>header2
>header3
something4
something5"

p str.scan(/(^>[^\n]+)([^>]+)/m).map { |header, lines| [header.to_sym, lines.strip] }.to_h
# {:">header"=>"something1\nsomething2\nsomething3", :">header2"=>"", :">header3"=>"something4\nsomething5"}
```

## File.foreach

If you're working on huge files, it might be a good idea to use :

```
headers = {}
last_header = nil

File.foreach('headers.txt') do |line|
  if line =~ /^>/
    last_header = line.chomp.to_sym
    headers[last_header] = ""
  elsif last_header
    headers[last_header] << line
  end
end

p headers 
#=> {:">header"=>"something1\nsomething2\nsomething3\n", :">header2"=>"", :">header3"=>"something4\nsomething5\n"}
```